# Python hcitool scan

Tags: python, bluetooth

I would like to use Python to check the output of the bash command `hcitool scan` for known MAC addresses.

Example: I have my phone's MAC address saved as a variable. Then, I check all MAC addresses identified by `hcitool scan`. Something like this:

```
for each (popen('hcitool scan') as $line)
   if ($line == $mymac)
      print 'Phone in the Bluetooth range';
   else
      print 'Your phone isn't in the Bluetooth range';
```

Comment: Why not use BlueZ directly?

Comment: This is the output i get when running inquiry.py pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo python inquiry.py performing inquiry... Traceback (most recent call last): File "inquiry.py", line 12, in <module> nearby_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices(lookup_names = True) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bluetooth/bluez.py", line 22, in discover_devices raise BluetoothError ("error communicating with local " bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError: error communicating with local bluetooth adapter

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is PHP. The $variable names give it away :)

For doing the same with Python have a look at [PyBluez](http://code.google.com/p/pybluez/%20PyBluez). Though it doesn't really support Python 3, someone may have started a port but I don't know where it is

Comment: This is the output i get when running inquiry.py

pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo python inquiry.py
performing inquiry...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "inquiry.py", line 12, in <module>
    nearby_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices(lookup_names = True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bluetooth/bluez.py", line 22, in discover_devices
    raise BluetoothError ("error communicating with local "
bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError: error communicating with local bluetooth adapter

Comment: It does support Python 3 now.